# Help me with the firebase tools

Tags: nodejs, npm

**Greetings everyone.**

I'm a new ubuntu 16.04 user. I installed my nodejs, npm and firebase tools.

But, after that I need to do the last step before deploying my static web.
Login to my firebase with npm.

I always get this output :

> $ firebase login firebase: command not found

from this following input :

> $ firebase login

I also installed the npm global package (jshint) with input :

> $ npm install -g jshint

and get this output

> /home/marco/.npm-global/bin/jshint ->
>   /home/marco/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/jshint/bin/jshint
>   + jshint@2.9.5 added 31 packages in 16.463s

Could someone help or tell me my mistake(s)?
Please.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Run this code in your terminal:

```sh
alias firebase="$(npm config get prefix)/bin/firebase"
```